# Как подставить переменную в SQL-запрос?

Tags: modx, mysql

Что-то у меня не получается подставить переменную в SQL-запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `poezdki` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

Не работает такая конструкция, а если напрямую прописать:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `poezdki` WHERE `id` = '5'");
```

то все ОК.  
Переменная - это id текущего пльзователя, система ModX.
Ввел переменную таким образом:

```
$id = '[[+modx.user.id]]';
echo 'ID пользователя:'. $id;
```

Результат дает, но вот в запросе не хочет работать.

UPD. Подставляю такое значение вручную, работает, чрез переменную выводит то дже значение, но не работает выборка. В чем проблема?

Comment: Покажи, что пишет 

    echo "SELECT * FROM poezdki WHERE id = '$id'";

Comment: Я тут для примера написал ID, но вообще желательно, чтобы по имени пользователя выборка происходила.
По твоему коду пишет:
SELECT * FROM poezdki WHERE usernames = 'test@test.ru'
Получатся, что оно подставляется? Но выборку не дает, может, из-за кавычек одинарных?

Comment: @Batyabest, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poezdki WHERE id = {$id}");
```

Попробуй так. И еще, если в переменной содержится число, то '' кавычки не нужны, и для безопасности явно приводить к типу `(int)$id`.

Comment: Не работает((